# Front-loading washing machine tub doesn't drain

Tags: water, doors, noise, washer

The water in my Frigidaire Affinity Front Load Washer accumulates and does not drain out of the rubber rim.  Also the washer door is making a humming noise while the machine is running.  If I press on the door it goes away but returns once I release the pressure on the door.

Comment: .....and the question is???

Comment: A photo would help. I'm not sure if you're asking about the tub draining or a little water at the seal. Is this a new development? Also, please ask just one question at a time. Take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

The shape of the rubber gasket in every front-loader I've looked at leads to a small puddle, maybe 20 cc or so.  This is nothing to worry about; if you really don't like it just dedicate a rag to soaking this up at the end of every laundry day.

The humming might be from a loose screw or plate on the door, or it might be that your pressure is transferring to the machine housing and that's what is actually vibrating.  Check around for any loose screws or improperly seated panels.  Less likely but possible is one of the feet is not solidly in contact with the floor.

Answer (score 0):

The humming could be a misaligned electrical latch or door. When the washer is running, the latch holds the door closed so you can't accidentally open it. If the part of the latch on the door doesn't quite go all the way into the part on the chassis, the electromagnet that holds the latch shut can hum. When you push the door in, you push the latch fully closed and the electromagnet is happy. Until you stop pushing, of course.